# Pullback in local coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, pullback

Let $M,N$-smooth manifolds and $$\chi:M\rightarrow N$$ is a map between them. Then if we have a map $$f:N\rightarrow R$$Then the pullback of $f$ is the smooth function $\chi^*f$ defined by $$(\chi^*f)(x)=f(\chi(x))$$

If we have local coordinates $x^a$ on $M$ and $y^i$ on $N$ then the following is true $$\chi^*(y^i)=\chi^i(x)$$ And I have a question - where does this follow? I do not quite understand the meaning of the last line.

Comment: Do you understand what is $\chi ^i$?

Comment: @ArcticChar I think this is coordinate functions on $N$

Comment: If it is a coordinate function on $N$, then it has nothing to do with $\chi$?

Comment: What are the domain and codomain of $\chi^*f$? I think you may be confusing pullback with function composition. The term "pullback" has a precise meaning, and I'm pretty sure this isn't it.

Comment: @ArcticChar I would say that I can determine the coordinates on $N$ as follows $y^i=\chi^i(x)$

Comment: @MarkSaving Some people, including myself, also call this composition pullback (especially when they think of functions as $0$-forms)

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks. I've just never heard that term used in this way. I assume dthat a pullback would refer to the ordinary category-theoretic definition of a pullback in the category of smooth manifolds, but it seems this is not the case.

Comment: @MarkSaving I think this is the standard definition of pullback in differential geometry. The only thing that I can replace the set $R$ with a manifold $A$

Comment: @ArcticChar I guess you're viewing maps $N \to \mathbb{R}$ as a contravariant functor in $N$, and the "pullback" is the action of this functor on morphisms.

Comment: For each $i$, $y^i$ is a real-valued function on $N$. The last line defines $\chi^i$ to be $\chi^i = \chi^*y^i = y^i\circ \chi$.

Comment: @MarkSaving No, generally on differential forms. There is more mathematics than category theory.